# Why does only writing data to Firebase Database cost me 12kB/minute in downloads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using native `Firebase Javascript SDK's` on IoT device running Node-red environment.

- My code consist only `WRITE` and `DELETE` operations on the Firebase
  RealtimeDatabase data.
- When the IoT device turns on the connection is also established.
- But other then that I never `READ` any data from Firebase Realtime
  database.

Even though I don't `READ` any data, when I looked this morning into the Firebase console I saw a graph that showed me constant `12kB/minute` downloads and `1` peak connection. I though some bot connected to my database. So I turned off my IoT device and I saw in the graph that also the connection went from `1` to `0` (so I am certain only my IoT device was connected to the database).

Also the downloads went from `12kB/minute` to `0kB/minute`:

[image]

[image]

- I will add my code below - but I am confused what data did I
  downloaded if I didn't use any `on`, `onChildAdded`, `onValue` etc.
  methods.
- I am pretty new to Firebase Database so if I am doing some rookie
  mistake just point me to the right direction.

### Why does my IoT device download any data when I am only using READ methods?

---

**Code which runs when the IoT device turn's on:**

```
//Load data from Global contexta
const app = global.get('app');
const database = global.get('database');
const firestore = global.get('firestore');
const auth = global.get('auth');


const firebaseConfig = {
  //my credentials 
};

//Set up Firebase
const fb_app = app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const fb_db = database.getDatabase(); //kdybychom měli vice projektu tak app dame do parametru
const fb_ft = firestore.getFirestore();
const fb_auth = auth.getAuth();

//Save the database reference to Global context
global.set('fb_app', fb_app);
global.set('fb_db', fb_db);
global.set('fb_ft', fb_ft);
global.set('fb_auth', fb_auth);
```

**Code that writes data every 1 second:**

```
const fb = global.get('database');
const fb_db = global.get('fb_db');

var timestamp = Math.round(msg.payload / 1000);
var UID = 'uid1';

var a1 = 0  + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var p1 = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
var t1 = 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);

//Send data to Firebase
const ref = fb.ref(
    fb_db,
    'device_realtime/' + UID + '/' + timestamp.toString()
);

fb.set(ref, {
    a1: a1,
    p1: p1,
    t1: t1
});
```

**Code that deletes data older then 60 seconds:**

```
const fb = global.get('database');
const fb_db = global.get('fb_db');

var timestamp1 = Math.round(msg.payload / 1000) - 60;
var timestamp2 = Math.round(msg.payload / 1000) - 61;
var UID = 'uid1';

//Delete old data from firebase
var reference1 = fb.ref(
    fb_db,
    'device_realtime/' + UID + '/' + timestamp1.toString()
);

var reference2 = fb.ref(
    fb_db,
    'device_realtime/' + UID + '/' + timestamp2.toString()
);

fb.remove(reference1)
fb.remove(reference2)
```

**Code that writes data every 1 minute:**

```
const fb = global.get('database');
const fb_db = global.get('fb_db');

var timestamp = Math.round(msg.payload / 1000);
var UID = 'uid1';

var a1 = 0  + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var p1 = 50 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
var t1 = 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);

//Send data to Firebase
const ref = fb.ref(
    fb_db,
    'device_trends/' + UID + '/' + timestamp.toString()
);

fb.set(ref, {
    a1: a1,
    p1: p1,
    t1: t1
});
```

**Screenshot of the entire flow:**

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the "OK" responses to your writes are 200 bytes each?

Comment: Can I somehow then turn off the `OK` responses? And if this is true - why it wouldn't be mentioned in the Firebase docs?

Comment: Probably because it's absolutely negligible when you get 10 GiB/month of network egress for free with Firebase and beyond that it seems to be $0.12/GiB. 10 GiB gives you, uh... 50 million of such responses per month.

Comment: In the docs `1GB/month` beyond the `10GB/month` free quota costs 1$ doesn't it? Or am I missing something? And yes I am not scared I won't be able to pay for this - I am just curios and want to learn about this behavior :D

Comment: I would probably hover my cursor on the little (?) next to the Downloads title - it would likely tell you what that figure really is. I was looking at the egress pricing only; I'd assume the "Realtime Database - GB downloaded" ($1/additional GB) is for actual result data downloaded from queries...

Comment: Ah! `Downloads account for all bytes downloaded from your database(s), including connection protocol and SSL encryption overhead, over 1-minute intervals. The free limit per project is 360 MB per day.` Now it makes much more sense! Thank you man! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the discussion in comments:

That Downloads figure takes into account all outbound traffic from the database, including e.g. any possible OK responses to writes made.

Based on the figures quoted and some napkin math, it seems that every write corresponds to about 200 bytes of data downloaded.